# What's the best way to logout with ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, cflogin

`cflogout` does not seem to clear the CFID and CFTOKEN values.  Is `cflogout` only used with `cflogin`?

In this instance, I am not using `cflogin`.  I am setting session variables because of the issues with `cflogin`.  It worked before CF11 Update 7, however, CF11U7 seemed to resolve the `cflogin` double issue.  Anyone else?

Is this all that I need?  If so, it's not working.

```
<cfset structDelete(session, "CFTOKEN")>
<cfset structDelete(session, "CFID")>
```

What is the best way to logout using ColdFusion?

Comment: I feel like cflogin/cflogout isn't particularly well-documented, but I'm pretty sure <cflogout> will only work on a previous <cflogin>.  Additional session vars will need to be unset manually.  To make sure you're not missing anything, use `<cfoutput> #StructKeyList(Session)# </cfoutput>` to view any other session keys that might be set in your app.

Comment: `cflogout` only uses `cflogin`. How do you currently identify they are logged in? Just delete the token you use to say they are logged in.  You could just delete the whole session `structClear(session)` but that is a bit of a sledge hammer approach.

Comment: what's identifying that a user is logged in? Is there a userID in session?

Comment: Thanks for the helpful feedback.  I set a loginrole session that I clear on logout which seems to be working.  The issue that I'm testing is that the login page is sometimes prompted twice when the cfapplication is reset.  Once I successfully login, the double login goes away.  I was trying to isolate if it's a session CFID/CFTOKEN issue.  It seems like the session variables are not sticking on the first login.  Testing that is what made me notice that I can't clear the CFID/CFTOKEN sessions.

Comment: So, it's only happening in Chrome.  I think it's a client issue.

Comment: FYI CFTOKEN and CFID exist outside of the session (as does jsessionid) as cookies. They are how the system knows to tie your request to the items in memory - they identify your session, but they are not your session. Does that make sense? If you were to delete the COOKIE then the session would remain (in memory of the server) but would no longer be tied to your request. make sense?

Comment: Thank you for explaining, Mark.  That makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<cfscript>
    StructClear(Session)
</cfscript>
```

This will delete ALL session variables.

(1)

```
<cfscript>
    StructDelete(Session.MySessionVariable)
</cfscript>
```

(2)

```
<cfscript>
    StructDelete(Session, "MySessionStructure")
</cfscript>
```

Will delete a specific variable (1) or structure(2) in the session scope.

Answer (score 5):

```
<cfset sessionInvalidate()>
```

This function will not only clear the session scope, but also invalidate the CFID/CFToken.

Answer (score 2):

```
<cfset StructDelete(SESSION,"user")>
```

Here user is the structure that i made during the login

Comment: This. Although I might go with `structClear(SESSION)` - anyone know the difference?

Comment: @TRose With the first you are deleting the key named "User" from the structure "session" - with the second you are blanking out the entire session. The second is more secure as it does not leave data lying about. Depending on the way you handle logins you may not even have a "USER" key anyway.